# Background color stops this.props.navigation.goBack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I've got a problem with `goBack` in react native. `This.props.navigation.goBack` works on the `TouchableOpacity` but when I add background color to the `View` element, it stops working. Moreover the color is not visible - I don't see any change in my emulator. Do you have any idea why background color stops `this.props.navigation.goBack`?

```
    const Header = ({onPressCloseArticle }) => (
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    <Text>Title</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonClose} onPress={onPressCloseArticle}>
      <Image
        source={require('Close.png')}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

export default Header;
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall and rerun the app again check if the behaviour is same as you mentioned otherwise if there is any error you will get information about that

Comment: I did it a few times, the behaviour is the same, on the other hand there is no error message :/

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem, but I can help you solve it.

If you are trying to configure `Custom Header`, you can use `withNavigation`.

**Header.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View,Text,TouchableOpacity,Image } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black',flexDirection:"row"}}>
    <Text>Title</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
      <Image
        source={require('./spiro.png')}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
      />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps MyBackButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(Header);
```

**Usage**

```js
import Header from "./Header"
...

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    // headerLeft instead of left
    headerLeft: <Header  />,
  };
```

I made Example. is here [Example Link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/navigation-back-button-props-example)

Comment: @WojciechNowaczyk  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?